# SQLITE get row continous value

Tags: sqlite, select, android-sqlite

I have a simple table. One of the example rows looks like this:

```
id | name |
1  | a    |
2  | a    |
3  | a    |
4  | b    |
6  | b    |
7  | a    |
8  | a    |
```

I want to get last continuous id.
so if i start at '1', the result should be '4'

in this example, the result should be '7'

```
3 |a |
4 |b |
5 |a |
6 |a |
7 |a |
10|a |
```

Only i now is that select all after my input number, and find continuous programmatically.

how can i do..?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not good at English.
i want find max continuous number.

Comment: 1-2-3-100-104 -> result : 3

Comment: 5-6-7-8-10-11 -> result : 8

Comment: 4-6-10-11-12-15 (from 10) -> result : 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this should work for you:

`select id from tableName t1 where not exists(select id from tableName t2 where t2.id=t1.id+1) and (id-(select count(*) from tableName t3 where t3.id<t1.id))=(select min(id) from tableName);`

If you want to start from `10`, it should be:

`select id from tableName t1 where not exists(select id from tableName t2 where t2.id=t1.id+1) and (id-(select count(*) from tableName t3 where t3.id<t1.id and t3.id>=10))=10;`

Comment: select id FROM tableName t1 WHERE t1.id >= 10 AND not exists(select id from tableName where id = t1.id + 1) order by t1.id LIMIT 1

Comment: @Soo it's okay as long as you don't require every integer between 10 and the output id to exist, it should be better than mine